# How to center the letters into the middle of a circle to create a sort of flashcard effect?

Tags: html, css, formatting, center

I am trying to center the letters into the middle of each circle I created, so that I can make a sort of flashcard effect. I need it to be permanently centered so that the text can change and still be in the center. Here is the code I have. It's on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Skullvapor/pen/RKqBOb).

## HTML

```
<div id="cover">
  <div class="red-box">
    <h1 id="red"> 뚱뚱한 고양이 </h1> 
  </div> 
  <div class="blue-box"> 
    똑똑한 고양이
  </div> 
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#cover {
  position:absolute; 
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0em; 
  border: 1em solid black;
  background:#dae0ed;
}
.red-box {
  background:#ef6258;
  width:50%;
  height: 50%;
  float:right;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:.1em solid black;
  box-shadow: .03em .03em 03em 0em #424447;
}
.blue-box {
  background:#6994ea;
  width:50%;
  height: 50%; 
  float:right;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:.1em solid black;
  box-shadow: .03em .03em 03em 0em #424447;
}
.green-box {
  background:#91c1a6;
  width:50%;
  height: 50%;
  float:right;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:.1em solid black;
  box-shadow: .03em .03em 03em 0em #424447;
}
.brown-box {
  background:#af8960;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float:right;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:.1em solid black;
  box-shadow: .03em .03em 03em 0em #424447;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  margin:0;
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-shadow: .03em .03em grey;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to have your boxes display content perfectly centered is to turn them into flex boxes. Try adding a class of `.box` to all of your boxes and using this markup:

```
.box {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Here is a link to [an updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpoJzo).

You can read more about using flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks so much! Like I said I am very new so that is why I have never heard of flexbox. Seriously thank-you this is so useful.

Comment: @Skullvapor of course! You are welcome, I'm glad this helped so much and if this answered your question you can use the checkbox under the voting arrows to mark it as "accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The flex-box example will work well with browsers that support it. If you need to support browsers that don't support flex-box, I would use this solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="contents">
     <div>Text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle > .contents {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle > .contents > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Note: The solution I have shown here will require an extra element. That's why I didn't modify your existing code. Also, you had the vertical align property in your example/jsfiddle. Vertical align property only works with tables.

Comment: According to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), flexbox with prefixes works in 97.5% of all browsers globally.

Comment: @DylanStark Not sure what your getting at here :) If you have to support the small percentage of browsers that don't support it, flexbox won't work. That's why I included this example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use position absolute combined with transform:

```
.red-box {
  position: relative;
  background:#ef6258;
  width:50%;
  height: 50%;
  float:right;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:.1em solid black;
  box-shadow: .03em .03em 03em 0em #424447;
  #red{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Here I modified your code using sass: https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/bgONQY?editors=0100